# How to maximize overlap integral

Tags: optimization

my question is on finding the function $p(x)$ that maximizes the overlap integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)p(x) dx$, where the site condition $\int_{\infty}^{+\infty}  p(x)dx=1$ holds (of course this is motivated to search some propability distribution) and $f(x)$ is given. Unfortunately applying techniques from variational calculus does here not work out. If one tries to maximize the functional with the technique of lagrange multipliers
\begin{align}
L[p(x),x,\lambda] =\int_{\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) p(x)dx-\lambda \left(\int_{\infty}^{+\infty} p(x)dx-1\right)
\end{align}
one gets $\lambda=f(x)$, which is utter nonsense. Moreover one gets no reasonable result for $p(x)$.
How do I get the right result, which should be somehow $p(x)=\delta(x-x_\max)$, where $\delta$ is the delta distribution and $x_\max$ is the global maximum of $f(x)$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think the problem is well-posed. Your proposed solution is not a function, so it makes no sense to take a functional derivative of $L$ with respect to it. Moreover, if we admit distributions, you could probably find an even better solution by taking $p(x)=\delta(x-x_m)+\alpha \delta'(x-x_m)$, and fixing $\alpha$ to some optimal value. Higher derivatives are allowed too, and they may even decrease the target function even more. The functional is probably unbounded from below anyway.

Comment: okay, allowing distributions might be dangerous, but the kind of optimazation-problem should be clear. Of course one should be only interested in physically relevant solutions and not in derivations of distributions

Comment: You are swamped by formalism. Instead of an infinite-dimensional vector space, take a two-dimensional one. Maximize $L=f_1p_1+f_2p_2$ subject to $p_1+p_2=1$.